# What is the limiting distribution of the Bayesian Filtering

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model, consistency, filter

I've got a question about the iterative Bayesian filtering, the general form of which is shown as follows:

$P(x|z_0,...z_{k+1})\propto P(z_{n+1}|x)P(x|z_0,...,z_k),\,k=0,1,\dots$.

$P(x|z_0)=P_0(x)$

where $x$ is the hidden state, $z_i\, (i\in \mathbb{N})$ are evidences and $P_0(x)$ is the initial distribution of the state $x$.

Suppose $z_1,\dots z_{n+1}$ are conditionally independent given $x$ from the $P(\bullet|x)$. Then when $n$ tends to infinity, will the posterior distribution $P(x|z_1,...z_{n+1})$ have a limiting distribution? If so, will the limiting distribution be irrelevant with the initial distribution $P_0(x)$? This seems to be related to the stationary distribution of Markov Chain (since the filtering process can be modeled as a HMM). But I have no idea how to prove it. Can anyone give any hints about the proof?

Comment: (+1) Small nitpick: $z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}$ are 'conditionally independent given $x$' rather than i.i.d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x|\dots)$ gets a Dirac on the real $x_{\rm true}$ if the $P(z|x)$ is parameterized by $x_{\rm true}$. It is not parameterized, then the Bayesian filtration finds only the closest projection in terms of the Kulback-Leibler divergence (i.e. the closest projection of $P(z)$ on the class $P(z|x)$). The only assumption on prior $P(x_0)$ is that it is nonzero for $x_{\rm true}$. For details and the proof, see [this](http://library.utia.cas.cz/separaty/historie/karny-0409379.pdf).

Comment: I should clarify this. My question is actually assuming that $x_i$ is the same for each $z_i$. However I'm also interested in the case of different $x_i$ and it's what I want to ask next.

Comment: @shionlau I misread the question (though the hidden-markov-model tag seems irrelevant). I deleted my comment.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Oh, sorry for the confusion. I think if the state transition only has one possible outcome (i.e. the same state), the question still falls into the HMM category, is this correct?